# I want to add new elements to an existing XML file with Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

I want to add new elements into an existing XML file. But I think I have not modified the existing script correctly.

PowerShell:

```
$pathToConfig = "C:\Temp\Config.xml"

#force the config into an XML
$xml = (get-content $pathToConfig)

#find the node to insert after
$foundNode = $xml.ACConfig.KfxDB

#build new node by hand and force it to be an XML object
$newNode = @"
<EBCAcquisition RestoreScannerSource="0" />
<ACIServer RemoteSite="1" DisableSharingProfiles="1">
<TransferTimeout>300</TransferTimeout>
</ACIServer>
"@

#add new node AFTER the configsections node
$newNode = $xml.ImportNode($newNode.appSettings,$true) 
$xml.configuration.InsertAfter($newNode,$foundNode) |out-null

#save file
$xml.Save("$pathToConfig.CHANGED.XML")
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ACConfig>
  <Services>
    <Licensing>
      <Service Key="Licensing\Licensing Service" Host="Y1234567" Protocol="http" Port="4949" />
    </Licensing>
  </Services>
  <Reporting Enable="0" />
  <CurrentVersion>11.0</CurrentVersion>
  <KfxDB>
    <SQL-Server>
      <Database>Database</Database>
      <StandardInstance>Test</StandardInstance>
      <UserID>sa</UserID>
      <Password>1234567</Password>
      <AuthenticationMode>SqlServer</AuthenticationMode>
    </SQL-Server>
    <IsDatabaseInstalled>1</IsDatabaseInstalled>
  </KfxDB>
</ACConfig>
```

Error Message:

> Failed to call the method because [System.String] does not contain a
>   method named "ImportNode". In line: 18 characters: 1
>   + $ newNode = $ xml.ImportNode ($ newNode.appSettings, $ true)
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> ```
>     + CategoryInfo: InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId: MethodNotFound   It is not possible to call a method for an expression that has the NULL. In line: 19
> characters: 1
> + $ xml.configuration.InsertAfter ($ newNode, $ foundNode) | out-null
> + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> ```
>
> ```
> + CategoryInfo: InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId: InvokeMethodOnNull   Error calling the method because [System.String] does not contain a method named Save.
> ```
>
> In line: 22 characters: 1
>   + $ xml.Save ("$ pathToConfig.CHANGED.XML")
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo: InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId: MethodNotFound

Comment: You import the xml as string. Use this: `[xml]$xml = (get-content $pathToConfig)`

Comment: Also, `$newNode` is a string and there isn't `.appSettings` member in a string object.